# Assign value inside tf.tensor

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow

I have a object `predict_wide_window`. Within it I have a variable `example`.

```
predict_wide_window.example value are:<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 12, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=

     array([[[ 1.    , 13.521 ,  6.257 ,  8.6   ],
             [ 2.    , 12.692 ,  8.0317,  8.8   ],
             [ 3.    , 12.692 ,  9.0498,  8.4211],
             [ 4.    , 13.198 ,  9.7643,  8.85  ],
             [ 5.    , 13.198 ,  9.7996,  7.25  ],
             [ 6.    , 13.198 , 10.1545,  8.    ],
             [ 7.    , 16.136 , 10.1307,  8.    ],
             [ 8.    , 16.136 , 10.2481,  8.    ],
             [ 9.    , 16.136 ,  9.7015,  7.7   ],
             [10.    , 13.521 ,  9.2827,  7.95  ],
             [11.    , 13.521 ,  9.5588,  7.7   ],
             [12.    , 13.521 , 10.4541, 10.    ]]], dtype=float32)>,
     <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 12, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
     array([[[ 8.8   ],
             [ 8.4211],
             [ 8.85  ],
             [ 7.25  ],
             [ 8.    ],
             [ 8.    ],
             [ 8.    ],
             [ 7.7   ],
             [ 7.95  ],
             [ 7.7   ],
             [10.    ],
             [ 7.85  ]]], dtype=float32)>)
```

**Objective:**
I want to change value in first row i.e. `predict_wide_window.example[0][0][0]` from

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 1.   , 13.521,  6.257,  8.6  ], dtype=float32)>
```

to [ 1., 15,  10,  5  ] .

So final`predict_wide_window.example[0][0][0]` should be

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 1.   , 15,  10,  5], dtype=float32)>
```

**What I am doing is**

```
predict_wide_window.example[0][0][0]=np.array([ 1., 15,  10,  5  ])
```

**ERROR:** But the error I get is

```
TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment
```

How can I manage this.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea because eager tensors are tensors that are immutable, meaning the value inside can't be changed, you have to use tf.Variable if you want to make a tensor that is changeable as such

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

pred_window = tf.reshape(tf.range(1 * 12 * 4, dtype=tf.float32), (1, 12, 4))
pred_window_var = tf.Variable(pred_window)
'''
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 12, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
        [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.],
        [12., 13., 14., 15.],
        [16., 17., 18., 19.],
        [20., 21., 22., 23.],
        [24., 25., 26., 27.],
        [28., 29., 30., 31.],
        [32., 33., 34., 35.],
        [36., 37., 38., 39.],
        [40., 41., 42., 43.],
        [44., 45., 46., 47.]]], dtype=float32)>'''

# Note that you must use the assign function along with the exact dimensions you are trying to fill up in this case here [1, 1, 4]
pred_window_var[:, 0:1, :].assign(tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1, 1]]], dtype=tf.float32))
pred_window_var[:, 1:2, :].assign(np.array([[[1, 1, 1, 2]]], dtype=np.float32))
'''
<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=(1, 12, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.],
        [12., 13., 14., 15.],
        [16., 17., 18., 19.],
        [20., 21., 22., 23.],
        [24., 25., 26., 27.],
        [28., 29., 30., 31.],
        [32., 33., 34., 35.],
        [36., 37., 38., 39.],
        [40., 41., 42., 43.],
        [44., 45., 46., 47.]]], dtype=float32)>'''
```